# How do you plot block shades of gray?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I basically want to plot 50 shades of gray... unrelated to the book! ;)

As far as I understand RGB values, if all three are the same value (or close to it), we get a shade of gray. E.g. (1, 1, 1) is nearly black and (254, 254, 254) is nearly white. Conclusion: I don't need a 3d array to plot shades of gray.

I got it working using a 3d array, as described, but I would like to plot them using a simle 2d array if possible.

Here we get the correct results, using a 3d array:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(10, 5, figsize=(20, 10))
fig.tight_layout(pad=0.5)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    shade = i * 255/49
    im = np.ones((4, 20, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * int(shade)    # using 3d array
    ax.imshow(im)
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', bottom=False, left=False, labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)
    ax.set_title('shade: {}'.format(shade))
```

[image]

Here when only using a 2d array of identical values (combined with the `cmap='gray'` argument) we get all black output:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(10, 5, figsize=(20, 10))
fig.tight_layout(pad=0.5)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    shade = i * 255/49
    im = np.ones((4, 20), dtype=np.uint8) * int(shade)       # using 2d array
    ax.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', bottom=False, left=False, labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)
    ax.set_title('shade: {}'.format(shade))
```

[image]

### How can I recreate the 3d array version using only 2d arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `imshow` by default normalizes your `cmap` such that the lowest value in your data maps to black and the highest to white. Since you only have one value, all your values are interpreted as the lowest value.

To fix this you need to tell `imshow` what the min and max *possible* values for your data are, as these are not always present in your image. This is done using the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments:

```
ax.imshow(im, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```